# Rigidity for Lie Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups

This may be a very dumb question but I was wondering if the following train of logic is correct:

1. We know a connected Lie group $G$ is isomorphic to the quotient $G\cong \tilde{G}/\Gamma$ where $\Gamma\cong \pi_1(G)$ is a discrete central subgroup of $\tilde{G}$.
2. We also know that an automorphism of $\tilde{G}$ that takes $\Gamma$ to $\Gamma$ will descend to the quotient and hence induce and autmorphism of $G$. Moreover, an automorphism of $\tilde{G}$ restricts to an automorphism of $\Gamma$.

It seems reasonable to assume that every automorphism of $\Gamma$ arises from an automorphism described in 2. However, is it true that every automorphism of $\Gamma$ extends to an autmorphism of $\tilde{G}$ (I suppose this is a type of rigidity result). If so then it seems that the automorphism group of $G$ is determined by the automorphism of $\Gamma$.

Comment: why does every auto of $\tilde G$ restrict to an auto of $\Gamma$?  Did you mean $G$ instead of $\tilde G$ there?

Comment: I should have said: every auto of $\tilde{G}$ that maps $\Gamma$ to $\Gamma$ restricts to an automorphism of $\Gamma$.

Comment: This is a good question. I am not sure of the answer. However, I would like to point out that your statements would not show that $\text{Aut}(G)$ is determined by $\text{Aut}(\Gamma)$. What your statements would show is that every automorphism of $G$ determines a unique automorphism of $\Gamma$. Every automorphism of $\Gamma$ extends to an automorphism of $\tilde{G}$ which results in an automorphism of $G$. But it would not imply that automorphisms of $\Gamma$ extend to unique automorphisms of $G$. In fact, this will almost never be true: take $G$ itself to be simply connected for example.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As you pointed out, this would show that $Aut(\Gamma)$ is determined by $Aut(G)$. After further thinking, it seems to follow from Mostow Rigidity.